# Prevent grep in R from treating "." as a letter

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector that contains text similar to the following:

```
text <- c("ABc.def.xYz", "ge", "lmo.qrstu")
```

I would like to remove everything before a `.`:

```
> "xYz" "ge" "qrstu"
```

However, the `grep` function seems to be treating `.` as a letter:

```
pattern <- "([A-Z]|[a-z])+$"

grep(pattern, text, value = T)

> "ABc.def.xYz" "ge"          "lmo.qrstu"
```

The pattern works elsewhere, such as on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).

How can I get `grep` to behave as expected?

Comment: I wonder how many more answers this question will bring. Looks like an epic dupe to me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg but there are so many packages to answer this question with! especially since it is impossible in base r!

Comment: My question wasn't "How to use regex in R", it was "Why does grep in R do this particular thing", so I wouldn't say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` is for finding the pattern.  It returns the index of the vector that matches a pattern.  If, `value=TRUE` is specified, it returns the value.  From the description, it seems that you want to remove substring instead of returning a subset of the initial vector.

If you need to remove the substring, you can use `sub`

```
 sub('.*\\.', '', text)
 #[1] "xYz"   "ge"    "qrstu"
```

As the first argument, we match a pattern i.e. `'.*\\.'`.  It matches one of more characters (`.*`) followed by a dot (`\\.`).  The `\\` is needed to escape the `.` to treat it as that symbol instead of any character.  This will match until the last `.` character in the string.  We replace that matched pattern with a `''` as the replacement argument and thereby remove the substring.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Could you explain the `.*\\.` syntax?

Answer (score 5):

`grep` doesn't do any replacements.  It searches for matches and returns the indices (or the value if you specify value=T) that give a match.  The results you're getting are just saying that those meet your criteria at some point in the string.  If you added something that doesn't meet the criteria anywhere into your text vector (for example: "9", "#$%23", ...) then it wouldn't return those when you called grep on it.

If you want it just to return the matched portion you should look at the `regmatches` function.  However for your purposes it seems like `sub` or `gsub` should do what you want.

```
gsub(".*\\.", "", text)
```

I would suggest reading the help page for regexs `?regex`.  The wikipedia page is a decent read as well but note that R's regexs are a little different than some others. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 4):

You may try `str_extract` function from `stringr` package.

```
str_extract(text, "[^.]*$")
```

This would match all the non-dot characters exists at the last.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern does work, the problem is that `grep` does something different than what you are thinking it does.

Let's first use your pattern with `str_extract_all` from the package `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text, pattern ="([A-Z]|[a-z])+$")
[[1]]
[1] "xYz"

[[2]]
[1] "ge"

[[3]]
[1] "qrstu"
```

Notice that the results came as you expected!

The problem you are having is that `grep` will give you the complete element that matches you regular expression and not only the matching part of the element. For example, in the example below, grep will return you the first element because it matches "a":

```
grep(pattern = "a", x = c("abcdef", "bcdf"), value = TRUE)
[1] "abcdef"
```

Comment: Regarding the last part... `regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern = "a", x))` or with `regexpr`